# How does a quantum circuit calculating the inverse of a non-injective function act?

Tags: quantum-gate, measurement, quantum-circuit

Lets say I have a non-injective function $f()$, adding image for reference. Now lets say I build a quantum circuit to calculate $f^{-1}()$. If the input register has the value $i$, does the output register have all the values $j$ in superpostion, such that $f(j)=i$ ? [image: non-injective function]

Comment: what would you think $f^{-1}(A)$ would be?

Answer (score 3):

This is essentially a matter of definition. If you design and build a function which you are claiming to be $f^{-1}$, you first have to define what the output will be if the input is $C$, and what you define will determine how you implement it. Outputting some sort of superposition might seem like a reasonable option, but mathematically the function is unlikely to behave how you would expect it to. But that might all come down to the context you're using it in.

Comment: The context I'm using it in is to find the different inputs which have the same image under $f$. You can think of $f$ as a function calculating some cube-roots in a finite field where cube-roots are not injective.

Answer (score 1):

Any operation on a quantum computer has to be reversible, measurement and reset being an exceptions. In your case the operation is not reversible as for C you have two possible inputs - 3 and 4. To implement your operation on QC you have to distinguish between 3 and 4. The most general approach is to copy input state together with the output. For example if input is $|3\rangle$, then output will be $|3\rangle|C\rangle$ and for input $|4\rangle$ you will have $|4\rangle|C\rangle$. Now, your operation is reversible.